# Display image in JSP (html)

Tags: java, html, image, jsp

I have a very unexpected hard time to display an image in my JSP-class. I have put my Image in this folder: `C:\Users\jacob\workspace2\BuildRoomClientProject\WebContent\img`. When I use `<img src="img/lund.png" height="50" width="50">` the image won't show, it's like eclipse cannot find any picture named `lund.png`. What am I doing wrong?

And this is my *JSP-code*:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%> 

<%@ page import = "org.ics.ejb.Building" %> 
<%@ page import = "org.ics.ejb.Room" %> 
<%@ page import = "org.ics.ejb.RoomId" %> 
<%@ page import = "java.util.List" %> 
<%@ page import = "java.util.Iterator" %>
<html> 
<head> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"> 
<title> 
Show Rooms 
</title> 
</head> 
<body bgcolor="Pink"> 
<h2> 
Rooms: 
</h2> 

<%List<Room> r = (List<Room>)request.getAttribute("rooms"); %>
<% for (Room r1 : r){
out.println(r1.getBname() + "  " + r1.getId().getrcode());
}%>

<p> 
</p> 

<form action="/BuildRoomClientProject/TestClientServlet" method="post"> 
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Tillbaka"> 
<input name="operation" value="searchbuilding" type="hidden"> 
</form> 
<img src="img/lund.png" height="50" width="50">
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Can you place the image in your war folder?

Comment: Where is your jsp file? Please share the project structure.

Comment: my JSP files is in this folder: C:\Users\jacob\workspace2\BuildRoomClientProject\WebContent

Comment: Do You have the same structure that I have shared?

Answer (score 1):

Create a folder `img` under your webapp folder in the parallel of `WEB-INF` folder and put the image `lund.png` there.

```
WebContent
|
|__abc.jsp
|__WEB-INF
|__img
   |
   |__lund.png
```

---

Try with simple jsp file as shown below:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=windows-1252"%>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Show Rooms</title>
</head>
<body bgcolor="Pink">
    <img src="img/lund.png" height="50" width="50">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Its working perfectly for me. Try it with simple jsp file having single line of `<img>` nothing else.

Comment: Copied your jsp-code and still not working for me... :/

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

I think that problem is that when you specify path in your jsp file (like `img/lund.png`), it sends request to your server to get this image. You probably defined servlet with `urlPattern = /` and your image path (`img/lound.png`) matches this pattern (`/` contains `/ing/lund.png`), so your custom servlet is executing for image request, but it doesn't contain any logic to return image.

**Solutions:**

- You can create servlet for files as described in this post: [FileServlet](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2007/07/fileservlet.html)
- Or you can change your custom servlet urlPattern so it would not intersect with you files folder. For example: `servlet_url_pattern = "servlets/myServlet"` and `images_folder = "img/myImages"`

P.S. I am new to servlets, so I may be wrong in some cases, but it works with my project.