# How to show image from database to jsp page in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jsp, shopping-cart

**Index.jsp**
this is my code to print 2nd column of image from table but it not work

```
<td><img src="<%out.print(rs.getString(2)); %>"
                            height="100px" width="100px"></td>
                        <td>
```

[Image not display in jsp page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjLNd.png)

[this is my database table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpwCw.png)

anyone help me to figure out why image not displayed in jsp page

Comment: Use the relative or absolute path. 1. Ensure the file upload is storing the file in the uploaded folder path. 2. Give a relative path or absolute path in the src location. i.e., <img src="/uploads/<%out.print(rs.getString(2)); %>"/>

Comment: Refer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922301/display-image-in-jsp-html

Comment: it means  having a uploaded  images in image folder then it working and  it is not working for direct display from table ?